# Caching PostgreSQL table - too many client connections

Tags: postgresql, performance, caching

I have a simple small PostgreSQL table with about 100 entries. A lot of clients (more then 100) are fetching this table with a simple query. Each client does about one request a second. Delayed data is ok.

I think it is not good that so many clients are doing so many requests - but please correct me if I'm wrong.

Now I though to reduce load on the database. We already have a caching mechanism using mongodb. Will I get any performance gain if the results are cached in mongo? Happy to hear alternative suggestions!

Comment: 1) Does each client fetch all the rows each time? Maybe they can get only the modified rows based on modified_on field. This can be a small optimization.
2) Make sure the clients use the connection pooling to database. This can reduce load on database. Seems like connection pool size of 1 is enough for your use case

Comment: I added today pgbouncer and hope it improves the performance. The table is really small, I think each client makes a costume query. The query is really fast don't think that is an issue. Rather the number of requests and connection. My intuition was that this is not good for postgres. Especially if number go up. Like 1000 clients.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no problem with many clients concurrently readin a small table. The table will be cached in memory. You can only lose by making your architecture more complicated than it has to be.

You need a connection pool, but that id an independent issue.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I have decided to use pgbouncer. Not 100% sure what the right settings are. Hope that it doesn't have to be finetuned. Right now everything is working. Will just check if the query is really cached in memory through explain.

Comment: The query is not cached, but the table is.